# How to change order with TypedQuery in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cxf, jpql

I wish to implement pagingation with FIQL support.
I am using apache cxf with JPA(Hibernate).
Here is sample example given for it http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-search.html#JAX-RSSearch-JPA2.0

```
SearchConditionVisitor<Order, TypedQuery<Order>> visitor
    = new JPATypedQueryVisitor<>(em, Order.class);

// connect FIQL cxf SearchCondition with our JPA visitor
searchCondition.accept(visitor);

// creeate JPA specific TypedQuery by our visitor
TypedQuery<Order> typedQuery = visitor.getQuery();

typedQuery.setFirstResult((page * perPage) - perPage);
typedQuery.setMaxResults(perPage);

// Run the query and return matching a complex FIQL criteria
return typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Every thing looks working including searching and pagination. 
It looks have no order by clause being use from generate sql log and seems follow database insertion order.
Now I wish to change the default sorting order. For example I wish to sort by Order id field in descending order. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You set the order where you set/generated the (Typed)Query, which you don't mention. You'd find that in any JPA docs, such as http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/query.html#jpql_ordering

Answer (score 5):

I can get it working with use of CriteriaQuery.

```
    JPACriteriaQueryVisitor<Order, Order> jpa
            = new JPACriteriaQueryVisitor<>(em, Order.class, Order.class);
    searchCondition.accept(jpa);
    CriteriaQuery<Order> cq = jpa.getCriteriaQuery();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    Root<Order> root = (Root<Order>) cq.getRoots().iterator().next();
    cq.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get("id")));
    TypedQuery<Order> query = jpa.getTypedQuery();
    query.setFirstResult((page * perPage) - perPage);
    query.setMaxResults(perPage);
    return query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was searching this solution all day!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the order after creating the query.

If you use MySQL, then maybe you can use an integer parameter in `ORDER BY :colnum DESC` to specify the column number by which to sort (starting at 1 from the selected columns only), but you cannot change direction.

PostgreSQL does not allow you to do this. I do not know how it is on other databases, though. With MySQL, the parameters are replaced by the SQL Driver, so it always receives the full query with escaped sequences. With PG, the query is first parsed by the server, the execution plan is created (including if and how to order the results) and then the parameters are sent.